# Extending a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Does this reasoning work for extending a vector field?

A vector field $X$ is defined on an open subset $V$ of a manifold $M$. Take a cover $U_\alpha$ of $V$ with $U_\alpha$ from the atlas. To define $Y$ (extending $X$) on the whole of $M$

1. if $p\in U_\alpha$ and $U_\alpha\subset V$, $Y_p = X_p$.
2. if $p\in U_\alpha$ and $U_\alpha$ is not a included in $V$, we look locally. On $\phi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$, we can extend the vector field using a function which goes down to zero differentially. we then go back to the manifold.
3. else, $Y_p = 0$

Comment: The function you're looking for is a bump function. You need to be a little careful with how you use them. In general given a closed subset $A$ of a manifold, you can find an open set $U$ containing it so that there is a bump function that is 1 on A and 0 outside the closure of $M-U$. See if you can use this to help extend your vector field!

Comment: @OsamaGhani I don't see it sorry. In A and outside of $M - U$, ok. But in between... I can see that on any given map, I can extend the vector field locally to make it go to zero differentially. But that is just my visual intuition and I wouldn't know how to right it. And I wouldn't know why if on each chart it is differential, on the whole it will stay a vector field.

Comment: @tomak : Can't always extend a vector field to the whole manifold.